# JQuery Slider in MVC issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5.1

[image]
[image]

So I am having an issue getting this JQuery slider to work. You can find it [here](http://jedrzejchalubek.com/glide/).
Under the src folder on their github I downloaded the jquery.glide.js file and the style.css file and inserted it into my code as best as possible. (still learning html and css coding) I don't get any errors from firebug and everything runs find except there isn't any sliding going on as you can see here from a screen shot of the slider. it just sits there. I could really  use some help getting this thing working or at least tell me what I am doing wrong or missing. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are calling `.glide()` on element the is not created yet. You should call it when the **[DOM is ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**:

```
$(function(){
    $(".slider").glide();
});
```